# Primefaces data table issue for Cannot find component with identifier

Tags: java, html, primefaces

I have following bug with my project.

SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":form:messages" referenced from "form_tab:tabView:form:tableList:loginButton".

This is my index.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form_tab">  

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  

    <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true">  

        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabBean.onTabChange}" update=":form_tab:growl"/>  

        <p:tab title="Godfather Part I" id="Godfather1">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
           <h:form id="form" >
           <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardBean.model}">  

           <p:panel id="sports" header="Status" style="text-align: center; width: 1210px">

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

            <p:dataTable id="tableList" var="table"   value="#{tableBean.table}"  editable="true" style="font-size: 10px; width: 500px" >

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" update=":form:messages"  onstart="return myFunction()" />   
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages " oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)" onstart="return myFunction2();" />

                                           <p:column  headerText="ID" style="width:30px">
                                               <h:outputText value="#{table.ID}" style="font: medium "/>
                                           </p:column>

                                           <p:column headerText="name" style="width:200px">
                                               <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.name}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                   <f:facet name="input">
                                                       <p:inputText value="#{table.name}" style="width:200px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                               </p:cellEditor>
                                           </p:column>

                                           <p:column headerText="Date" style="width:100px">
                                               <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.initiateddate}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.initiateddate}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                               </p:cellEditor>
                                           </p:column>

                                           <p:column headerText="Status">
                                                <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                       <h:outputText value="#{table.status}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                     <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.status}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor >
                                           </p:column>

                                          <p:column headerText="TestingDoc">
                                                <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                       <h:outputText value="#{table.testingdoc}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                     <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.testingdoc}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor >
                                           </p:column>
                                          <p:column headerText="TestingStartDate">
                                                <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                       <h:outputText value="#{table.teststartdate}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                     <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.teststartdate}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor >
                                           </p:column>      
                                          <p:column headerText="ScheduledEndDate">
                                                <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                       <h:outputText value="#{table.scheduledenddate}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                     <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.scheduledenddate}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor >
                                           </p:column>         
                                          <p:column headerText="TestStatue">
                                                <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                       <h:outputText value="#{table.teststatus}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                     <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.teststatus}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor >
                                           </p:column>     
                                          <p:column headerText="Revised">
                                                <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                       <h:outputText value="#{table.revised}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                     <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.revised}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor >
                                           </p:column>     
                                          <p:column headerText="Launch">
                                                <p:cellEditor>
                                               <f:facet name="output">
                                                       <h:outputText value="#{table.launch}" />
                                               </f:facet>
                                                     <f:facet name="input">
                                               <p:inputText value="#{table.launch}" style="width:100px"/>
                                               </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor >
                                           </p:column> 

                                            <p:column headerText="TestStatus">
                                                <f:facet name="TestStatus">#{msgs.buttonHeader}</f:facet>
                                                     <h:outputLink value="http://localhost:8080/dashboardtables_4/faces/new.xhtml" >
                                                     <h:outputText value="#{table.egoname}" />
                                            <!--<h:commandButton value="{table.egoname}" />-->
                                                     <f:param name="route" value="#{table.egoname}" />
                                                     </h:outputLink>
                                            </p:column>

                                            <p:column headerText="LaunchStatus">
                                                <f:facet name="LaunchStatus">#{msgs.buttonHeader}</f:facet>
                                                    <h:outputLink value="http://localhost:8080/dashboardtables_4/faces/launch.xhtml" >
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{table.name}" />
                                            <!--<h:commandButton value="{table.name}" />-->
                                                    <f:param name="route" value="#{table.name}" />
                                                    </h:outputLink>
                                            </p:column>

                                           <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">
                                               <p:rowEditor/>

                                           </p:column>

                                                   <f:facet name="footer" id="foot"> 

                                                       <h:panelGrid columns="8" cellpadding="5"   id="pane" >
                                                        <h:outputLabel  value="e_name" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.e_name}"  id="ename" required="false" label="ename" />


                                                        <h:outputLabel value="initiate_date" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.initiate_ddate}" id="initiatedate" required="false" label="initiatedate" />


                                                        <h:outputLabel value="agreement_status" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.agreement_status}" id="agreementstatus" required="false" label="agreementstatus" />

                                                        <h:outputLabel value="testing_doc" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.testing_doc}" id="testingdoc" required="false" label="testingdoc" />

                                                        <h:outputLabel value="teststart_date" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.teststart_date}" id="teststartdate" required="false" label="teststartdate" />

                                                        <h:outputLabel value="scheduledend_date" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.scheduledend_date}" id="scheduledenddate" required="false" label="scheduledenddate" />

                                                        <h:outputLabel value="test_status" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.test_status}" id="teststatus" required="false" label="teststatus" />

                                                        <h:outputLabel value="revised_end" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.revised_end}" id="revisedend" required="false" label="revisedend" />

                                                        <h:outputLabel value="launc_status" />
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.launc_status}" id="launcstatus" required="false" label="launcstatus" />

                                                        <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="AddNew" update=":form:messages" actionListener="#{tableBean.addNew}" oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)" onstart="return myFunction3();"/>
                                                        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear" oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)"/>
                                                        </h:panelGrid>

                                            </f:facet>
                                       </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>  

        </p:dashboard> 



        </h:form>

            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab title="Godfather Part II" id="Godfather2">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />  
                <h:outputText value=""/>  
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab title="Godfather Part III" id="Godfather3">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                <h:outputText value=""/>  
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:tab>  

    </p:tabView>
```

What is the reason for that?

Thank you

Comment: please give me an any idea to this issue?

Comment: What is the form_tab here in which component u have given this id?

Comment: form_tab is the id of the form that is in the beginning of the code. I edit my code again.plz check it.

Comment: Sure,if remove the all updated attributes then it executed with out any bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try `update="growl"` without any form id it should work.Please let me know if you have any issue.If you will want to ajax update for more than one component you can use  `update="growl,secondid,thirdid"`
Please tray this code and let me know if it is working or not?

```
<h:form id="form">  

<p:panel id="panel" header="New Person" style="margin-bottom:10px;">  
    <p:messages id="messages" />  
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">  
        <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *" />  
        <p:inputText id="firstname"   
            value="#{pprBean.firstname}" required="true" label="Firstname">  
            <f:validateLength minimum="2" />  
        </p:inputText>  
        <p:message for="firstname" />  

        <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname: *" />  
        <p:inputText id="surname"   
            value="#{pprBean.surname}" required="true" label="Surname"/>  
        <p:message for="surname" />  
    </h:panelGrid>  
</p:panel>  

<p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" update="panel,display" id="ajax"  
         actionListener="#{pprBean.savePerson}" />  

<p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" actionListener="#{pprBean.savePerson}"   
        ajax="false" />  

<p:commandButton value="With Icon" actionListener="#{pprBean.savePerson}" id="withIcon"   
        update="panel,display" icon="ui-icon-disk" />  

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{pprBean.savePerson}" update="panel,display" id="iconOnly"  
        icon="ui-icon-disk" title="Icon Only"/>  

<p:commandButton value="Disabled" disabled="true" id="disabled" />  

<p:panel id="display" header="Information" style="margin-top:10px;">  
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
        <h:outputText value="Firstname: " />  
        <h:outputText value="#{pprBean.firstname}" />  

        <h:outputText value="Surname: " />  
        <h:outputText value="#{pprBean.surname}" />  
    </h:panelGrid>  
</p:panel>
```

Comment: Can you please post what code you tested or do onet hing remove updated and tell me if page rendered or not?

Comment: Sure,if remove the all updated attributes then it executed with out any bug

Comment: <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabBean.onTabChange}" />

Comment: What about this ajaxevent? and i added a code please try this code in your project and let me know if it works or not?

Answer (score -1):

```
rubel/php.apk>woouej>?"{{$#R4or}oi4jji4r|<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  

<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true">  

    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabBean.onTabChange}" update=":form_tab:growl"/>  

    <p:tab title="Godfather Part I" id="Godfather1">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
       <h:form id="form" >
       <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardBean.model}">  

       <p:panel id="sports" header="Status" style="text-align: center; width: 1210px">

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

        <p:dataTable id="tableList" var="table"   value="#{tableBean.table}"  editable="true" style="font-size: 10px; width: 500px" >

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" update=":form:messages"  onstart="return myFunction()" />   
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages " oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)" onstart="return myFunction2();" />

                                       <p:column  headerText="ID" style="width:30px">
                                           <h:outputText value="#{table.ID}" style="font: medium "/>
                                       </p:column>

                                       <p:column headerText="name" style="width:200px">
                                           <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                               <h:outputText value="#{table.name}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                               <f:facet name="input">
                                                   <p:inputText value="#{table.name}" style="width:200px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                           </p:cellEditor>
                                       </p:column>

                                       <p:column headerText="Date" style="width:100px">
                                           <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                               <h:outputText value="#{table.initiateddate}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.initiateddate}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                           </p:cellEditor>
                                       </p:column>

                                       <p:column headerText="Status">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.status}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                 <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.status}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor >
                                       </p:column>

                                      <p:column headerText="TestingDoc">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.testingdoc}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                 <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.testingdoc}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor >
                                       </p:column>
                                      <p:column headerText="TestingStartDate">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.teststartdate}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                 <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.teststartdate}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor >
                                       </p:column>      
                                      <p:column headerText="ScheduledEndDate">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.scheduledenddate}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                 <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.scheduledenddate}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor >
                                       </p:column>         
                                      <p:column headerText="TestStatue">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.teststatus}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                 <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.teststatus}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor >
                                       </p:column>     
                                      <p:column headerText="Revised">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.revised}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                 <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.revised}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor >
                                       </p:column>     
                                      <p:column headerText="Launch">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                           <f:facet name="output">
                                                   <h:outputText value="#{table.launch}" />
                                           </f:facet>
                                                 <f:facet name="input">
                                           <p:inputText value="#{table.launch}" style="width:100px"/>
                                           </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor >
                                       </p:column> 

                                        <p:column headerText="TestStatus">
                                            <f:facet name="TestStatus">#{msgs.buttonHeader}</f:facet>
                                                 <h:outputLink value="http://localhost:8080/dashboardtables_4/faces/new.xhtml" >
                                                 <h:outputText value="#{table.egoname}" />
                                        <!--<h:commandButton value="{table.egoname}" />-->
                                                 <f:param name="route" value="#{table.egoname}" />
                                                 </h:outputLink>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column headerText="LaunchStatus">
                                            <f:facet name="LaunchStatus">#{msgs.buttonHeader}</f:facet>
                                                <h:outputLink value="http://localhost:8080/dashboardtables_4/faces/launch.xhtml" >
                                                <h:outputText value="#{table.name}" />
                                        <!--<h:commandButton value="{table.name}" />-->
                                                <f:param name="route" value="#{table.name}" />
                                                </h:outputLink>
                                        </p:column>

                                       <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">
                                           <p:rowEditor/>

                                       </p:column>

                                               <f:facet name="footer" id="foot"> 

                                                   <h:panelGrid columns="8" cellpadding="5"   id="pane" >
                                                    <h:outputLabel  value="e_name" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.e_name}"  id="ename" required="false" label="ename" />


                                                    <h:outputLabel value="initiate_date" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.initiate_ddate}" id="initiatedate" required="false" label="initiatedate" />


                                                    <h:outputLabel value="agreement_status" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.agreement_status}" id="agreementstatus" required="false" label="agreementstatus" />

                                                    <h:outputLabel value="testing_doc" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.testing_doc}" id="testingdoc" required="false" label="testingdoc" />

                                                    <h:outputLabel value="teststart_date" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.teststart_date}" id="teststartdate" required="false" label="teststartdate" />

                                                    <h:outputLabel value="scheduledend_date" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.scheduledend_date}" id="scheduledenddate" required="false" label="scheduledenddate" />

                                                    <h:outputLabel value="test_status" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.test_status}" id="teststatus" required="false" label="teststatus" />

                                                    <h:outputLabel value="revised_end" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.revised_end}" id="revisedend" required="false" label="revisedend" />

                                                    <h:outputLabel value="launc_status" />
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{tableBean.launc_status}" id="launcstatus" required="false" label="launcstatus" />

                                                    <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="AddNew" update=":form:messages" actionListener="#{tableBean.addNew}" oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)" onstart="return myFunction3();"/>
                                                    <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear" oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)"/>
                                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                        </f:facet>
                                   </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>  

    </p:dashboard> 



    </h:form>

        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>  

    <p:tab title="Godfather Part II" id="Godfather2">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />  
            <h:outputText value=""/>  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>  

    <p:tab title="Godfather Part III" id="Godfather3">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
            <h:outputText value=""/>  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>  

</p:tabView>
```

[rubelx2.webs.com](http://rubelx2.webs.com)